# Replace element by XPath

Tags: xpath, xml-namespaces, citrus-framework

I try to replace some element of my input XML in Citrus Framework.

My Spring context contains:

```
  <citrus:namespace-context>
    <citrus:namespace prefix="def" uri="http://sample.com/xmlns/2005"/>
  </citrus:namespace-context>
```

My input file starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns0:canonicalMessageHeader xmlns:ns0="http://sample.com/xmlns/2005">
            <ns0:headerVersion>1.0</ns0:headerVersion>
            <ns0:bodyVersion>1.0</ns0:bodyVersion>
            <ns0:trackingInfo>
                <ns0:eventHandlerInitInfo>
                    <ns0:processInfo>
                        <ns0:adapterTrackingId>214F27DF-E1FB-4E84-9122-390C5876ABD2:1</ns0:adapterTrackingId>
                        ...
```

My endpoint is configured in that way:

```
<send endpoint="jms:topic:Order.Request?timeout=10000&amp;connectionFactory=DEVconnectionFactoryFrom">
                        <message>
                            <resource file="com/sample/citrus/messages/input/SalesOrderTo.xml"/>
                            <element value="${track}" path="SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Header/def:canonicalMessageHeader/def:trackingInfo/def:eventHandlerInitInfo/def:processInfo/def:adapterTrackingId"/>
```

I have the following error:

```
Can not evaluate xpath expression 'SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Header/def:canonicalMessageHeader/def:trackingInfo/def:eventHandlerInitInfo/def:processInfo/def:adapterTrackingId'
        at com/sample/citrus/SalesOrderToIT(sequential:45)
        at com/sample/citrus/SalesOrderToIT(send:48-82)
Caused by: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: org.apache.xpath.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: def
```

What's the possible cause of this error?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global namespace declaration support is missing in Citrus when overwriting message elements in a send operation via XPath. This issue has been tracked: https://github.com/christophd/citrus/issues/331

In the meantime you have to use the exact same namespace prefix as in the message template file - in your case `ns0:`

Also you could throw away XPath overwrite and use the dot notated Node overwrite like this:

```
<send endpoint="jms:topic:Order.Request?timeout=10000&amp;connectionFactory=DEVconnectionFactoryFrom">
    <message>
        <resource file="com/sample/citrus/messages/input/SalesOrderTo.xml"/>
        <element value="${track}" path="Envelope.Header.canonicalMessageHeader.trackingInfo.eventHandlerInitInfo.processInfo.adapterTrackingId"/>
    </message>
</send>
```

The dot notation is not based on namespaces but uses the local element names for finding the element in the message template. Obviously not as powerful as XPath but it works with current version of the framework.

Comment: I have no idea why use the prefix ns0 does not work for me :( However the solution with dots works! Big thanks!

Comment: The `ns0` might not work for you because the namespace is not declared in the root element `SOAP-ENV:Envelope` but in a child element. All that is not of importance anymore once the mentioned fix for the issue on global namespace support is in place.

Answer (score 1):

You defined *nso* as namespace prefix in XML but then use *def* on the XPath, should be *nso*.

Comment: I suppose this is not the case:   http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/2.6.2/html/xpath.html  describes the namespace-context element in Citrus context which is related to this problem.

Comment: It is, check 'XML namespaces in XPath' int that page.